# Why is the overloaded == operator function saying that 2 parameters is too many

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

The MS Visual c++ 2010 compiler is telling me the operator== has too many parameters, but
let's it pass if I only put one. What's going on here? I got the function right out of Stroustrup's book, I"m pretty sure he knows how to overload an operator in c++.

```
class Book
{
    public:

    Book(){}

    Book(long long isbn,string  ttl, string  athr, int cpyrght_dt)
    :ISBN(isbn), title(ttl), author(athr), copyright_date(cpyrght_dt) {}
   //...
    const long long & Return_ISBN  () const {return ISBN;           }

    bool operator==(const Book& a, const Book & b)
    {
            return a.Return_ISBN()==b.Return_ISBN();
        }

  private:

    long long  ISBN;
    //....


  };
```

Answer (score 12):

You defined `operator==` as a method (member function), so it has an implicit `this` argument of type `Book*`. Either use that or lift the definition outside the class. Since it doesn't use any private members, I'd do the latter.

Comment: So you are  saying I have to use the "this" pointer, eg This.Return_ISBN()==a.Return_ISBN()... If I define the function outside the class do I need to declare it as a friend or like any other member function inside the class?

Comment: @user2904033 You should declare it as a `friend` only if it needs access to non-public data members or member functions. In this case, if `Book::Return_ISBN()` is a public member function, there'd be no need to declare it as a friend

Answer (score 4):

A two-argument operator overload goes outside of the class definition.

```
class Book
{
    ...
};

bool operator==(const Book& a, const Book & b)
{
    return a.Return_ISBN()==b.Return_ISBN();
}
```